# How to map a public URL using Spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security

I need in my web 2 types of URLs, one with access restrictions and one without it.
This is the schema:

myApp:

1. myApp/*.do        <-- Authorization required
2. myApp/public/*    <-- No Authorization required

The (1) URLs works fine, but I don't know how to implement / configure spring for (2). This is my actual configuration of servlet-mapping:

**Web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And in **context-security.xml** I have the following for the public access:

```
 <http pattern="/public/**" security="none"/>
```

I tried to add in Web.xml one more url-pattern with:

```
<url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>
```

But this doesn't work fine, I can access to all urls with authorization required without being logged using: myApp/public/xxx.do.

Should I create another servlet only for public URLs, or there is something more simple?

Edit:

My **context-security.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- Debug -->
    <!-- 
    <debug />
    -->
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <!-- No securizamos los recursos públicos -->
    <http pattern="/public/**" security="none"/>

    <http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="myAppAuthenticationEntryPoint">

        <intercept-url pattern="/ProcessResponseServlet" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/CallAuthenticationServlet" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/ReturnAuthenticationServlet" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login.jsp"
            default-target-url="/index.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error"  
            />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <remember-me />
    </http>

    <!-- myApp authentication entry point -->
    <beans:bean id="myAppAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="com.home.myApp.webapp.security.myAppAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Autenticación de pruebas-->
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider ref="mockProvider">
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="mockProvider" class="com.home.myApp.webapp.security.MockAuthenticationProvider" >
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Are you using Spring security?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that if I only use <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> I can only map URLs ending with ".do", but I need this only for the private web site. My public web site must accept all extensions, something like  <url-pattern>/public/*</url-pattern>. But if I do this, I got access to my private website with the url /myApp/public/....do.

Comment: What do you want to do with URLs matching both specs like `/public/foo.do` ?

Comment: I want to implement a public URL that return some serialized data in json or xml format, but if the format is not specified it must be json by default. So I need to configure a public URL that match with the pattern myApp/public/*, but without access to the private controllers, I mean, in my web you should be able to do: myApp/cars/list.do if you are logged  but  not myApp/public/cars/list.do or atleast not calling the same controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Spring security.
1. Add to your web.xml Filter for Spring Security (for example)

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher.xml
            /WEB-INF/context-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

2. Add to your context-security.xml

   ```
     <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">
       <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll"/>
       <intercept-url pattern="/res/**" access="permitAll"/>
       <intercept-url pattern="/*.do" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

   </http>
   ```

Comment: I edited my post with my full context-security.xml, I think that I am already using spring security.

Comment: But you should add springSecurityFilterChain to your web.xml. It will check your request. And you should add security-context configuration location in web.xml. I wrote in my answer.

Comment: You can send your web.xml and security context and I'll correct it

Comment: And your code 
    <http pattern="/public/**" security="none"/> replace to <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll"/> in first place in <http ...>